# Is there a name for this problem, which involves determining the fewest supersets of a bounded size which contain all input sets?

Tags: algorithm

I've encountered this problem a few times, and have written an algorithm which is able to solve it, but in my Googling I can't seem to find any discussion of the problem. Let me attempt to state it clearly:

Given as input a set of sets, each having up to N elements, determine a set of output sets that fulfill these criteria:

1. For each output set S_out, `len(S_out) <= N`. (Output sets have a bounded size)
2. For each input set S_in, there exists an output set S_out such that S_out is a superset of S_in (or they are equal). (Output sets contain all input sets)
3. The goal is to minimize the number of output sets. (Fewest output sets possible)

I have solved a specific variant of this problem in the past using a simulated annealing algorithm [(link)](https://github.com/charasyn/eb-png2fts/blob/with-map-data/palettepacker.py). I am currently trying to adapt this code to a more general library which can be used for other purposes, but I don't know what to call this problem.

An example of associated input and output sets are:

```
N = 9
inputs = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [1, 14, 15],
    [21, 22, 23, 24],
    [1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 23],
    [1, 23, 24, 25],
    [1, 23, 24, 26],
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
]
outputs = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
]
```

Does anyone know if this problem has a pre-established name? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a very slight variant of ***[`Set Cover Problem`](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Set_covering_problem)***. Generally, in classic Set Cover Problem, you would be given a universal Set `U` and a collection `S` of subsets of `U`. The objective would be *to find the smallest sub-collection of `S` that covers the entire universal set `U`*.

Having said that, we cannot exactly classify it under `Set Cover problem` because of the additional constriants that are kept like *the maximum size of the output sets (N)*, and *that each output set must be a superset of an input set*. So I'm afraid it cannot be given a specific name but `Set cover problem` comes close maybe if that helps.

---

##### Worth Reading:

1. [**Hitting Set Problem**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hitting-set-problem-is-np-complete/)